# How to get all the clicked checkboxes in an array?

Tags: android

I have 16 checkboxes in my layout. I want to write a method that will return all the selected checkboxes in an array, but i am not getting a clue how to do it.

I can do it by checking all the checkboxes one by one but that does not seem to be a good approach.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you adding checkboxes dynamically or are they in your layout?

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the checkboxes in an array of checkboxes and then run a for loop to see which are checked and which are not